# pass value between promises and function

Tags: javascript

when i run code get this error:

cant find variable: flagData

how can return(pass) data from promises implement(i use promises in another function)

```
resultOTP = OTP.fetchData(uniqueId, mobileNumber)

    .then((data) => {

      data.map((data)=>{
        if(data.message == "-1"){

          var flagData = 0
        }
        else {
          var flagData = 1
        }
      })


    })


    alert(flagData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the variable is not defined in the right scope and even if it was it wouldn't have worked since you have an async call in which you are a changing the value, you might as well use async await like

```
async function fetchData() {
  const response = await OTP.fetchData(uniqueId, mobileNumber);
  let flagData = -1;
  if(response) {
     response.map((data)=>{
        if(data.message == "-1"){
          flagData = 0
        }
        else {
          flagData = 1
        }
      })
  }
  alert(flagData)
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to keep your promises, put your alert() INSIDE the then callback.

Comment: thanks, it's worked